# how do I pass argument to a shell script from xcode build phases

Tags: xcode, shell

I have a "run script" phase as one of my build phases in XCode 5.
Now I want to pass arguments to my script. For instance I want XCode to invoke my script this way:

```
/path/myscript DEBUG IPHONESIMULATOR
```

if the current build configuration is Debug for iphone simulator

or this way :

```
/path/myScript RELEASE IPHONEOS
```

if the current build configuration is Release for iphone os

or this way:

```
/path/myScript DEBUG IPHONEOS
```

if the current build configuration is Debug for iphone os

How Can I achieve that?

Thanks,

baba

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a lot of environment variables set by xcode by default and you when you add a User-Defined value in project/target build settings. You can list all of them when your run script phase starts and you will see them in the build detailed log (switch on "Show environment variables in build log" in your run script settings settings)

**BUILD_TYPE** is f.e Debug or Release depending on what type of build you do actually

Comment: Thanks it works. I actually used CONFIGURATION and also PLATFORM_NAME variables. Also in order to visualize the variables in the log I had to write "env" (without quotes) in my script.